# Select two way binding not working in angularjs 1.4.0

Tags: angularjs

Select two way binding works on ng-click for the time until select option is manually changed from the dropdown in angularjs 1.4.0

HTML:

JS:

```
$scope.splitMerchants =[
        {id: 1,         label: 'Edit'},
        {id: 2,         label: 'Open'},
        {id: 3,         label: 'Close'},
        {id: 4,         label: 'Close1'},
        {id: 5,         label: 'Close2'},
        {id: 6,         label: 'Close3'},
        {id: 7,         label: 'Close4'}
    ];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.page = $scope.splitMerchants[0];

$scope.paginationPreviousButton = function(){
            $scope.currentPage--;
            if ($scope.currentPage <= 0) {
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
            }
            $scope.page = $scope.splitMerchants[$scope.currentPage-1];
};

$scope.paginationNextButton = function() {
           $scope.currentPage++;
           if($scope.currentPage > $scope.splitMerchants.length) { 
                $scope.currentPage = $scope.splitMerchants.length;
           }
           $scope.page = $scope.splitMerchants[$scope.currentPage-1];
};

$scope.paginationDropdownChange = function(page) {
            $scope.currentPage = page.id;
};
```

Expected Result:
The ng-model to be updated onn ng-click of buttons after the dropdown value is updated manually.

Actual Result:
ng-model isnt getting updated once the dropdown is manually updated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value of "currentPage" is not getting updated.

You can use $watch to track when the value of the "page" variable changes and update "currentPage" like so:

```
$scope.$watch('page', function(page){
  $scope.currentPage = page.id;
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/40vq1yab/1/